# how to get data in server side rendering using redux in nextjs

Tags: next.js

I'm new in `Nextjs` and `Reactjs` I created a shopping website and I used redux in it, I fetch my data using redux and I want to do server-side rendering in my project I don't know how to use my redux function to fetch data in my server-side rendering function to get data from the server, here is my code:

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Head from "next/head";

import Modal from "../../../components/UI/modal/Modal";
import List from "../../../components/products/List";
import TopBar from "../../../components/products/TopBar";

import { useRouter } from "next/router";

import { useSelector, useDispatch, connect } from "react-redux";
import * as ProductAction from "../../../store/actions/ProductAction";
import * as PreLoading from "../../../store/actions/PreLoadingAction";
import Filters from "../../../components/products/Filters";

const MainCat = (props) => {
  const [view, SetView] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState();
  const [items, setItems] = useState(true);
  const [addMessage, setAddMessage] = useState(false);
  const [sort, setSort] = useState("asc");
  const [showSort, setShowSort] = useState(false);

  const products = useSelector((state) => state.products.availablMainProducts);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const router = useRouter();

  const MainCat = router.query.maincat;

  const loadProducts = useCallback(async () => {
    setError(null);
    try {
      await dispatch(ProductAction.fetchMainCatProduct(MainCat));
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err);
    }
  }, [dispatch, setError, MainCat]);

  useEffect(() => {
    props.setPreLoading(true);
    setItems(true);
    loadProducts().then(() => {
      setItems(false);
      setTimeout(() => {
        props.setPreLoading(false);
      }, 1000);
    });
  }, [dispatch, setItems, loadProducts, MainCat]);

  if (error) {
    console.log("error => ", error);
  }

  const colView = () => {
    SetView(false);
  };
  const liView = () => {
    SetView(true);
  };

  const handleAlert = () => {
    setAddMessage(!addMessage);
  };

  const handleSort = (param) => {
    if (sort != param) {
      props.setPreLoading(true);
      setTimeout(() => {
        props.sortProducts(products, "maincat");
        props.setPreLoading(false);
        setSort(param);
      }, 500);
    }
  };

  const handleShowSort = useCallback(() => {
    setShowSort(!showSort);
  }, [setShowSort, showSort]);

  const handleFilter = (filter, type) => {
    props.filterProduct(products, filter, "maincat", type);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>s2Vintage || Products</title>
      </Head>
      <div style={{ minHeight: "100vh" }}>
        <div className="container-fluid pe-5 ps-5 row m-0">
          <Filters
            data={props.filter}
            brand={props.brands}
            doFilter={handleFilter}
          />
          <TopBar
            setCol={colView}
            setList={liView}
            sortHandle={handleShowSort}
            clickSort={handleSort}
            sortShow={showSort}
            getView={view}
          />
          {!items && products.length > 0 ? (
            <List
              data={products}
              listType={view}
              setAlert={handleAlert}
              pageLimit={5}
              dataLimit={25}
            />
          ) : (
            <div className="row m-0 mt-4 justify-content-center product-view">
              <h3 className="text-center">
                Oops! NO item found please change your filter.
              </h3>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
      {addMessage && (
        <Modal setClose={handleAlert}>
          <div
            className="alert alert-light bg-light p-4"
            role="alert"
            style={{
              position: "fixed",
              top: "50%",
              left: "50%",
              transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
              zIndex: 9,
            }}
          >
            <svg
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              width="100"
              height="100"
              fill="currentColor"
              className="bi bi-check2 text-success"
              viewBox="0 0 16 16"
              style={{ margin: "0px auto", display: "block" }}
            >
              <path d="M13.854 3.646a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-7 7a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-3.5-3.5a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708L6.5 10.293l6.646-6.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z" />
            </svg>
            <hr></hr>
            <h6 className="text-center text-success">
              Item added to your cart.
            </h6>
            <br></br>
            <button
              type="button"
              className="btn btn-outline-success"
              style={{ margin: "0px auto", display: "block" }}
              onClick={handleAlert}
            >
              OK
            </button>
          </div>
        </Modal>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    loading: state.preLoading.loading,
    brands: state.categories.availablBrands,
    filter: state.categories.availablFilters,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    setPreLoading: (loading) => {
      dispatch(PreLoading.handleLoading(loading));
    },
    sortProducts: (itmes, page) => {
      dispatch(ProductAction.sortProduct(itmes, page));
    },
    filterProduct: (items, fId, page, fType) => {
      dispatch(ProductAction.filterProduct(items, fId, page, fType));
    },
  };
};

export const getServerSideProps = async (param) => {
  console.log("all item", param);

  return { props: { data: "data array" } };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MainCat);
```

I know the code I wrote for server-side rendering does nothing because I don't know how to start it. I also read this article from [Nextjs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#server-side-rendering) official website.

Comment: For now (from what i understand) you are fetching data from your store using useSelector in the body of your page component, you need to place this logic in the getServerSideProps method to enable SSR.

Comment: `useSelector` is a hook and we can only call hooks inside the body component

Comment: Yes yes, but you need to put its logic in the getServerSideProps method to enable SSR

Comment: now I understand what you mean, do I have to get data from props or it's not necessary?

Comment: What do you mean 'get data from props' ?

Comment: Yes exactly, like `props.data` because I don't want to

Comment: Please read https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props

Comment: I'd also recommend you check out their official example: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux.